# how to create ARO's users and groups in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Hi I am Confused at creating the ARO users and groups and in which controller they 
  are defined
  Please help me Thanks in Advance

Comment: There are a lot aco manager plugins which can automatically create all aros/acos for you, you should google for it.

Answer (score 0):

ACL in general can get confused and complicated. Most times ACL is overkill for most APPs we develop anyway. I think Role Base Authentication with admin routing is much easier to setup and is enough for most situations. On my first CakePHP I developed, I used ACL, but did not actually need it, although it was a good learning opportunity. I am currently upgrading/redesigning to 2.0 and I am using role based for that site, with admin and members.

If you are trying to learn, I would say go for it and use the following CakePHP tutorial: [CakePHP Simple Acl Controller Application Tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html). To manage it, it can be very difficult. I would suggest the following plugin: [Alaxos - Plugin ACL 2.0](http://www.alaxos.net/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl_2.0). The down side with this, is that is takes a long time to process when you need to make a simple change like adding a function to an existing controller, that might not be worth it, specially if you are using shared hosting with execution limition.

Bottom line: Use it if you REALLY/ABSOLUTELY need for your site. If not stay away from ACL.